# Node JS 7.3.0 and WebStorm 2016.3.2: IDE always debugs with "--inspect"

Tags: node.js, debugging, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Ever since upgrading to node v7.x, WebStorm *always* starts the debugger with the `--inspect` flag and there is no option to disable this in the run/debug configuration.

I want the same debugging experience as before (debugging within WebStorm) and not use the new DevTools wizardry.

How can I stop the `--inspect` flag from being added when the debugger starts? Or, alternatively, is there an undocumented override, like `--inspect=false`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately no:( it's a known issue, see [WEB-24629](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-24629). Hidden option for turning dev tools protocol support off (`js.debugger.node.use.inspect=false`) will be included in next 2016.3 update - see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-24629#comment=27-1809582.

For now the only workaround is downgrading Node.js to 6.x:(
Full Node 7 support (using v8 inspector) will be available in 2017.1

Comment: Ah, what a shame. Thanks for sharing the link to the ticket! I've downgraded node for now and will upgrade once 2017.1 is out. :-)

Comment: Just in case you know: in the ticket it mentions that the non-inspect-debugging protocol is set to be removed from `node` (it references a `node` PR). When the new debugger lands - will it be integrated with WebStorm to keep the current workflow going, rather than having to work with Chrome DevTools?

Comment: yes. WebStorm 2017.x will use inspect protocol for debugging Node 7+, and current protocol for earlier versions

Comment: Thanks @lena, but I guess the debugging will be integrated into the IDE, rather than having to use DevTools? Just want to be able to set breakpoints in WebStorm instead of Chrome. :)

Comment: sure it will be integrated in IDE:)

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to lena's post. I've found that the bug is in Webstorm 2016.3.2 so you only have to downgrade to Webstorm 2016.3.1 to get the functionality back with the latest Node 7.x